# Add namespace for SOAP elements

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

When testing a SOAP web service with [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/), the tool generates the following soap envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:v2="http://xmlns.mydomain.com/sales/schema/quotation/v2">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <v2:AddUpdateQuotationRequest>
      <v2:UserId>UserId</v2:UserId>
      <v2:PublicQKey>8de6cf8d-ea38-434d-a636-aac3a1c45999</v2:PublicQKey>
    </v2:AddUpdateQuotationRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but when I add a reference to the web service in Visual Studio and test the web service, the soap envelope is missing the namespace and has the following format:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AddUpdateQuotationRequest>
      <UserId>UserId</UserId>
      <PublicQKey>8de6cf8d-ea38-434d-a636-aac3a1c45999</PublicQKey>
    </AddUpdateQuotationRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I know that accordingly to this [article](https://cmatskas.com/changing-soap-message-data-and-namespaces-with-c/) it is possible to add the namespace after the soap message is created by implententing [IClientMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx).

With that said, here are my two questions:

1. Why is the soap envelope generated from SoapUI different than the one generated with Visual Studio?
2. Is there any other/easier way to add the namespace to the soap message other then implementing [IClientMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) as explained in the aforementioned link?